# Dependent selects with value change and disable attr on change

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have some dependent selects with ids from `#no1 to #no10`. What I am trying to achieve is to clean the value from all dependable selects in the chain.

for example, if `#no1` has value then `#no2` disabled attr is removed and the user can select a value. The same happens with `#no3 (if #no2 is not empty)`, `#no4 (if #no3 is not empty)`, and so on.

I need if user select "Empty" in `#no2, then #no3,#no4,#no5,#no6,#no7,#no8,#no9,#no10` disable attr become true and the selected value is set to Empty.

Also, I am wondering if there is a way to simplify the script, especially the `if` section

I have tried using `.click()` for each element but it seems that it wasn't right.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#no1,#no2,#no3,#no4,#no5,#no6,#no7,#no8,#no9,#no10', function select() {
  var no1 = $("#no1").val();
  var no2 = $("#no2").val();
  var no3 = $("#no3").val();
  var no4 = $("#no4").val();
  var no5 = $("#no5").val();
  var no6 = $("#no6").val();
  var no7 = $("#no7").val();
  var no8 = $("#no8").val();
  var no9 = $("#no9").val();

  if (no1 != null && no1 != "" && no1 != "Empty") {
    $('#no2').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no2').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no2').val('Empty');
    $('#no3').val('Empty');
    $('#no2').val('Empty');
    $('#no2').val('Empty');
    $('#no2').val('Empty');
    $('#no2').val('Empty');
    $('#no2').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no2 != null && no2 != "" && no2 != "Empty") {
    $('#no3').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no3').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no3').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no3 != null && no3 != "" && no3 != "Empty") {
    $('#no4').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no4').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no4').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no4 != null && no4 != "" && no4 != "Empty") {
    $('#no5').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no5').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no5').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no5 != null && no5 != "" && no5 != "Empty") {
    $('#no6').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no6').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no6').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no6 != null && no6 != "" && no6 != "Empty") {
    $('#no7').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no7').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no7').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no7 != null && no7 != "" && no7 != "Empty") {
    $('#no8').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no8').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no8').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no8 != null && no8 != "" && no8 != "Empty") {
    $('#no9').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no9').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no9').val('Empty');
  }
  if (no9 != null && no9 != "" && no9 != "Empty") {
    $('#no10').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#no10').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#no10').val('Empty');
  }

});
$("#no1,#no2,#no3,#no4,#no5,#no6,#no7,#no8,#no9,#no10").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <span>Main carousel order</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no1">
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no2" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no3" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no4" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no5" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no6" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no7" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no8" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no9" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no10" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/largan/q47ah6e5/4/)

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: @palaѕн, you are absolutely right. Added a demo link now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DRY way to achieve this is to use the same `class` on all the select elements. Then you can retrieve the index of the one which raised the event and disable/enable all the following ones, based on the selected value. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.foo', function select() {
  let $select = $('.foo');
  let index = $select.index(this);
  let $next = $select.eq(index + 1)
  
  if (this.value == 'Empty') {
    $next.val('Empty');
    $select.filter(`:gt(${index})`).val('Empty').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $next.prop('disabled', false)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <span>Main carousel order</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no1">
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no2" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no3" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no4" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no5" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no6" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no7" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="no8" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no9" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control foo" id="no10" disabled>
        <option selected>Empty</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it nicely and super simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just noticed something... if you select an option different than "Empty" after you selected a value, all others get their value clean. The idea is only if the value is Empty, the next values to be cleaned and disabled

Comment: Thanks Rory. That fixed it!

Comment: And one more question if I may. I am trying to execute the logic as soon as the page is loaded with $(document).ready(function(){, also tried with load in the event, but didn't work. Any idea what could I do?

Comment: If you want this to execute as soon as the page loads, add `.first().trigger('change')` to the end of the above JS code

Comment: Somehow, it doesnt work. Here is an example of the exact case https://jsfiddle.net/largan/q47ah6e5/9/

Comment: When I said add it to the end, I meant using the correct syntax, not literally :) https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/eboufrns/